# String to Int (using loop) in C

Tags: c, string, for-loop, pointers, integer

In this example showing how to convert string to `int`:

```
int string2num (char *s) {
  int a = 0;
  for (; *s; s++)
    a = a*10 + (*s - '0');
  return a;
}

int main (void) {
  printf("==> %d\n", string2num("1234"));
  printf("==> %d\n", string2num("1234") + 1);
  printf("==> %d\n", string2num("1234") + string2num("1"));
  return 0;
}
```

... please explain what `(*s -'0')` represents?

Comment: You should go through the concept of pointers in C.

Comment: And then get familiar with ASCII codes for number characters.

Comment: Please explain what you don't understand. Is it `*s`, or `'0'` ?

Comment: @PM77-1 This code is not dependent on ASCII.  `*s - '0'` well defined even on rare non-ASCII encoding.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I dont understand '0'

Comment: `'0'` is the same as `48` and it means the ASCII code of the character `0`. This is proibably explained in the first chapters of your learning material.